# Actualizar uma label com o texto da dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Na minha label aparece todos os grupos:

> ABC

Devia aparecer apenas um grupo escolhido pela dropdown,
Exemplo:

> A

JS:

```
  $("#GrupoID").change(function () {

            document.getElementById("grupoupdate").innerHTML = $("#GrupoID").text();

        });
```

Label:

```
  @Html.Label((string)@ViewBag.Letra, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @for = "grupoupdate", @id="grupoupdate" })
```

Dropdown:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GrupoID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "GrupoID", "LetraGrupo"), "" , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Se fizer   `document.getElementById("grupoupdate").innerHTML = $("#GrupoID").val();` aparece o Id correcto na label.

Comment: O id que chega ao script está correto. "GrupoID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar o texto da `label` use o seguinte seletor com jQuery:

```
$("#GrupoID option:selected").text();
```

E para atribuir tal texto à sua `label`:

```
$("#grupoupdate").text($("#GrupoID option:selected").text());
```

A pseudo-classe `selected` obtém o texto do item selecionado no `select`, ou seja, no seu `DropDownList`.

Comment: Não funciona. Entra na função, mas não modifica o valor.

Comment: Ok, funciona. Foi erro meu de sintaxe.